# Type error: function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) does not override anything

Tags: solidity, erc-20

My smart contract defines an interface for `transfer` for an ERC20 token. Here is the definition of the `transfer` in ERC20 token contract:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.3.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"
contract ERC20Token is ERC20 {
     ...
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
            require(mustBeDude(msg.sender), "msg.sender must be on chain");
            require(mustBeDude(recipient), "Recipient must be on chain");
            super.transfer(recipient, amount);
        }
    ...
   }
```

The interface is defined as below:

```
interface ERC20Token {
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool); //<<== cause error below
}
```

[image: Type error message]

The definition of `interface` did not change anything. So what could cause the error?

Comment: There is code missing. After fixing the snippet to make it compile there's no error like the one you indicate.

Comment: Hi `Ismael`, sorry what is the code missing? I copied and pasted the function definition to interface.

Comment: The code snippet in the question compiles after a few fixes and works as expected, so the error is not in that part of the code so  it should be elsewhere.